# Flex: implementing TextInput restrict in spark table gives error

Tags: apache-flex

I'm creating a Flex table in which one column is editable. I want to restrict the user's input to certain characters. The following code gives an `Could not resolve <s:itemEditor> to a component implementation` error. Anyone know how to resolve this?

```
...
<fx:Array>
    <supportClasses:MyColumn ... />
    <supportClasses:MyColumn editable="true" ...>
        <s:itemEditor>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:TextInput restrict="0-9a-zA-Z"/> 
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemEditor>
    </supportClasses:MyColumn>
    <supportClasses:MyColumn ... />
    ...
</fx:Array>
...
```

Where MyColumn is a class and function as follows:

```
import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;
public class MyColumn extends GridColumn
{
    ...
    public function MyColumn(headerText:String="header" width:Number=100 ...)
    {
       this.headerText=headerText;
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to your issue on [this blog post.](http://life.neophi.com/danielr/2007/01/could_not_resolve_to_a_compone.html)

The issue is that the mxml compiler gets confused when the namespaces don't match (`supportClasses:` and `s:`). The fix is very simple:

```
<supportClasses:MyColumn editable="true" ...>
    <supportClasses:itemEditor>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:TextInput restrict="0-9a-zA-Z"/> 
        </fx:Component>
    </supportClasses:itemEditor>
</supportClasses:MyColumn>
```

Comment: @ggkmath Ah. I think i may have a solution for you. Take a look at my edited answer.